# Adaptation of Cows and Bulls

Tags: cipher, mastermind

So as all of you know, [Cows and Bulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) is a pen and paper adaptation of the popular board game [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). I would like to design a game that would allow duplicate numbers for the code and assign perhaps a third variable called **"milk"** to ascertain the number of repetitions in the code.

We will be playing with ***five digits*** instead of four, so what exactly would be the guidelines we would have to follow in order to accommodate **"milk"** as an additional parameter? Please explain with examples as well.

Comment: You could add any new information you want as long as the solution could be uniquely deduced. Are you asking us to design a game for you? If so, that's not on-topic here.

Comment: In the boardgames.stackexchange.com, there were no relevant tags that could be associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I think that one way you could implement the **"milk"** is to provide it as a third rating for each guess. The "milk" number would reflect how many of the colours that are present in the guess and the solution that also have the correct number of repetitions. For example:

if the solution was AABCD, and the guess was ABCDE there would be 1 bull, 3 cows and 3 milk (bottles?), and if the guess was instead AACDE, there would be 2 bulls, 2 cows and 4 milk bottles. This measure would always be less than or equal to the sum or the bulls and cows. When the solution is found, then the milk number will of course be 5.

Comment: Is there somehow maybe we could tweak it to know whether the "milk" number was a cow or a bull? Or maybe avoid it altogether if the number is in a bull position? @micsthepick

Comment: @JavaiMaster The milk number counts both cows and bulls.

Comment: Okay Thanks. This'll be accepted as the correct answer.